# I need a relation which is not reflexive, not symmetric, and not transitive

Tags: relations

I need an example of a relation which is simultaneously not reflexive, not symmetric, and not transitive.  Any accessible examples?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a\sim b$ iff $b=a+1$.

Comment: For any people $x, y$, try "$x$ loves $y$" :)

Comment: @Shaun But what about the narcissists?  For all narcissists, $x$ loves $x$. :P

Comment: Not all people are narcissists, @anorton $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Shaun whoops.  I was getting "not reflexive" confused with "irreflexive"

Comment: A fun follow-on to your question is: what is the size of the smallest set on which you can define such a relation?

Comment: @EricLippert $3$? $a \not\to a$, $a \to b \to c$, $a \not\to c$, $b \not\to a$,. If it were only "not reflexive, not transitive", then $2$ would be sufficient ($a \sim b$, $b \sim a$, $a \not\sim a$).

Answer (score 57):

Here's a non-mathematical one: "is the father of".
You are not your own father. You are not your father's father. Your father's father is not your father.

Comment: This is a really great one! +1

Comment: It's actually stronger than "not reflexive, symmetric or transitive", it's *ir*reflexive ($\forall x, x \not\sim x$), *a*symmetric ($x \sim y \Rightarrow y \not\sim x$), and *anti*transitive ($(x \sim y \wedge y \sim z) \Rightarrow x \not\sim z$).

Comment: Note: [does not work for grandfathers.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw&feature=kp)

Comment: “Luke, I am your ….” :)

Comment: I'm not complaining, just observing: this is in some sense the same answer as Dario's comment to the question.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah, I see "$a$ is the predecessor of $b$". Good observation.

Answer (score 16):

Think of three points $u, v, w$ with relation $R = \{(u, v), (v, w) \}$. So $u$ is related to $v$ and $v$ is related to $w$. This is not reflexive since $(u,u) \notin R$, not symmetric because $(v, u) \notin R$ and not transitive because $(u, w) \notin R$.

Answer (score 11):

What beats what in [Roshambo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors) or "Rock, Paper, Scissors" is such a relation.

1. not reflexive: rock does not beat rock.
2. not symmetric: rock beats scissors, but scissors does not beat rock.
3. not transitive: rock beats scissors and scissors beats paper, but rock does not beat paper.

The same is true of "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock".

Answer (score 7):

A simple one is : Define $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $(x,y)\in R$ if and only if $x-y=10$.

Answer (score 6):

On $\mathbb{N}$, consider
 $$a \sim b \iff a +2b = 5,$$
then

- $1\nsim 1$,
- $3\sim 1$ but $1 \nsim 3$,
- $3\sim 1, 1 \sim 2$ but $3 \nsim 2$.

Comment: Please don't use a symbol that's a variant of "$=$" for a relation that has none of the properties of equality!

Comment: @DavidRicherby It has been edited.

Answer (score 6):

How about:  "is the square of", defined on the set of positive integers?  In other words,
$$a \sim b \iff a=b^2$$

This relation is not reflexive (most numbers are not their own square), not symmetric (if $a$ is the square of $b$ then in most cases $b$ is not the square of $a$) and not transitive (if $a$ is the square of $b$ and $b$ is the square of $c$ then in general $a$ will not be the square of $c$).

Answer (score 6):

Minimal example:

$X = \{0,1,2\}$

$R = \{(0,1),(1,2)\}$

Answer (score 4):

Less than, but close:
 $$a \sim b \iff a < b  \ \ \text{ but } \ \ a > (b-1)$$

So

- $1\nsim 1$,
- $0.5\sim 1$ but $1 \nsim 0.5$,
- $0\sim 0.5$, $0.5 \sim 1$, but $0 \nsim 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Why not $a\sim b$ if and only if either $a=3$ and $b=4$ or $a=4$ and $b=5$?

Comment: Whoops, right you are! I’ll add another point.

Answer (score 3):

Take any directed acyclic graph amd the arcs form an irreflexive, asymmetric antitransitive relation of its nodes. Then add some loops (not to all nodes), back-arcs (not to all of them) and some skip-forward arcs (not to all directed paths) and you have a more general relation with your restrictions.

Ex: 
1) Strong version: a->b, b->c, c->d, a->e
2) Then add: a->a, b->a,a->d

Comment: Velcome to our site!